# Using events within Kendo dropdown select

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have the code below using `select`, but this is just giving me the `dataItem`, not the event of the select. Is there a way to do this? Or get the event from the dataItem?

```
var combo = $('#id').data("kendoComboBox");
combo.select(function (dataItem) {
  // do something with an event here?
  return dataItem.Id === id && dataItem.Name === name;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to bind to the select event, as can be read [here in the documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox/events/select):

Subscribing to the event during the initialization:

```
$("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
  dataSource: [ "Apples", "Oranges" ],
  select: function(e) {
    var item = e.item;
    var text = item.text();
    // Use the selected item or its text
  }
});
```

Subscribing to the event after the initialization:

```
function combobox_select(e) {
  var item = e.item;
  var text = item.text();
  // Use the selected item or its text
}

$("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
  dataSource: [ "Apples", "Oranges" ]
});

var combobox = $("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.bind("select", combobox_select);
```

Using `combo.select(object)` like in your code calls a method that gets or sets the currently selected item and doesn't register the select event. You can read about it [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox/methods/select).